# How to pack Database to c# application?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have finished my project, I also put 2 files .mdf and .ldf into folder "debug" of project.  but when I bring it to another computer, it doesn't work.

I use connection string like this.

```
class LoadFixture
{
    public static SqlConnection con = null;
    public SqlConnection conDB()
    {
        string connect = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Fixtures;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect);
        return con;
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You are aware you try to connect your _local_ database, right? You are bringing _what_ exactly? Your .mdf and .ldf files?

Comment: you are not connecting to the mdf and ldf files. you are connecting to database server. Try attach/import the data to the new database server.

Comment: @SonerGönül It means If I move the program to another computer, the program still run

Answer (score 2):

In order to able to access locally copied mdf file you need update your connection string, to point to the location of mdf file. You can do so by changing you connection with following:

```
    Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Please note that |DataDirectory| points to app_data folder of your solution. Or you can just hard code the path of the database file.